# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`price`, `category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (20, 3, 2020-12-11 07:00:34, 2020-12-11 07:00:34))

What's my fault?

Products Table:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments("id");
        $table->string("product_name")->default('');
        $table->decimal("price" ,5,2);
        $table->string("photo", 100)->default('');
        $table->text("description")->nullable();
        $table->integer("user_id")->unsigned();
        $table->integer("category_id")->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users")->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreign("category_id")->references("id")->on("categories")->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
```

ProductController Store func.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        "product_name"=>"required",
        "price"=>"required|integer",
        "user_id"=>"required|integer",
        "category_id"=>"required|integer",
    ]);

    $product = new Product([
        "product-name" => $request->get("product_name"),
        "price" => $request->get("price"),
        "user_id" => $request->get("user_id"),
        "category_id" => $request->get("category_id"),
    ]);

    $product->save();

    return redirect("products")->with("success","Products added.");
}
```

Model :

```
protected $table = 'products';
protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'photo', 'description', 'created_by', 'category_id'];
```

Comment: Welcome to So ... check your fiilable  property in model

Comment: Hi sir, I added Product model in my post. Can you check it for me pls?

Comment: `$fillable = ['user_id']` add `user_id`

Comment: I added that but I have a new error. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bootcamp`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: remove `cascadeOnUpdate()` from migration and re run migration

Comment: I got the same error again

Answer (score 0):

According to [eloquent mass assignment documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment), you should set fillable property of the class to be able to use `create` and `update` methods.

You can put `user_id` in the **fillable** array of the **Product** class or set **guarded** array to an empty array.

```
Product 
{
    fillable=[
        'user_id',
        ... // other attributes

    ];
}
```

Or

```
Product 
{
    guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: I added this but ı have a new error. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bootcamp`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: You should not both operations of `Update` and `Delete` on cascade. Remove one of them.

Comment: [Mysql cascade on delete reference](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) for more info about what `on cascade` does. It removes data from child tables automatically when you delete a record on parent. For example when you delete a user, it remove the product which referenced to it via `user_id`.

Comment: I removed update operation but ı got same error again

Comment: Did you run `migrate:fresh`?

Comment: yes ı run and than chech it but ı got same error again

Answer (score 0):

When you use this method

```
$product = new Product([
    //array
]);
```

It is actually 'filling' your model.

Same as
$product = new Product();
$product->fill($array);

## Option 1

Update your models $fillable properly to include user_id or replace is with guarded and only add the columns you DONT want to be able to be filled. Guarded is my personal favourite because if you add extra columns to your database you dont have to manually add every one as fillable.

## Option 2

Keeping user_id guarded is a good idea especially if you do

```
$product = new Product([
    $request->all()
]);
```

Because users can hack their own input and change things they shouldn't.

Instead columns such as user_id should be manually set like so

```
$product = new Product([
    $request->all();
);

$product->user_id = $request->get("user_id");
```

Comment: I did this changes. But ı got different error. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `products` (`product_name`, `price`, `category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Iphone 11, 1, ?, 2020-12-11 10:23:38, 2020-12-11 10:23:38)). I add nullable operator for category_id but after that ı got same error for photo column.

Answer (score 0):

In your database, the column name is "product_name". But in your model, your `fillable =['name'.....]` . Change it to 'product_name'. This is a little late to answer this, but I hope others may find it helpful. Use `protected $guarded = [];` Or check your fillable first.